# As create json file with data in JavaScript, and send that file for JSONP other domain

Tags: javascript, sql, json, dns, jsonp

I need your help with a big doubt.

Question: As I can create JSON file (with data) from JS code?

The reason is which I need use JSONP, and I wanna take that data from other domain (i.e. http://www.example.com/data/clients.json?callback=?), but this data are storage in a DB (WebSQL) and I need which that data is written in the json file (i.e. clients.json)

Please I need your help because three days ago I try do this, but I don't find yet the answer.

P.S.: Sorry for my english, not is my native language.

## EDIT

Sorry my question is confused. I try again but for steps.

I need to write a JSON file with data or records from a DB (WebSQL). Actually my functions are working well (add record, update record, delete), but I need to put that data in a json file because, I'll use the next code for get the data from other domain.

```
(function($) {
    var url = 'http://www.example.com/scripts/clients.json?callback=?';
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        console.dir(json.sites);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work. You need an HTTP server in order to serve HTTP requests. Browsers are not fit for this purpose.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you getting any error messages?  Can you show us any code snippets?

Comment: Ok, I edit and try again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-domain AJAX request behaving oddly on Android phone's native browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440518/cross-domain-ajax-request-behaving-oddly-on-android-phones-native-browser)